# Tool to convert ThreeJS code to WebGL?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

Does anyone know of a ThreeJS to WebGL converter that exists? Alternatively could you give me some insight on how I would make a ThreeJS to WebGL converter?

Comment: Three.js will build  a series of WebGL commands based on the parameters of it's 'object model'. It translates JavaScript properties into pure WebGL code.... basically, Three.js does exactly what you're asking, by converting JS to WebGL

Comment: Yes but how would I export the actual WebGL code? For instance, how would I grab the WebGL code from this http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-webgl-rotating-cube/

Comment: BTW this is general and not directed at anyone specifically, but why would someone down vote this question or any other for that matter if A. they're not sure what it is asking or B. Didn't care enough to look into it. Remember people on here are just trying to learn be mindful of that.

Comment: @AlexW Then is there a way to export the WebGL code before its compiled by the browser, using chrome dev tools or something?

Comment: You'll need to dig around the Three.js output in it's core. It's been a while since I've been very familiar with it, but it will pass parameters to the WebGL context in this file https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js

Answer (score 8):

Three.js is a WebGL-based 3D rendering engine, or should I say, library.

What Three.js does is all pure WebGL, there is no need for conversion of any kind. The code is just a bit abstracted so instead of you manually creating buffers, enabling vertex arrays and creating shaders, you can simply load model, select material and issue a draw call.

Three.js code is already a webGL code, just sugarcoated so it's easier to use.

Regarding the WebGL and OpenGL. WebGL is like some older version of the OpenGL. While newer versions (4.x) of OpenGL have bunch of new features, WebGL is very similar to OpenGL 2.0 (ES) specification. It means that is lacking features, but code can easily be converted between OGL2.0 and WebGL.

WebGL is a JavaScript API. That means that you write functions specific to WebGL technology in JavaScript, and those functions actually communicate with your GPU. So JavaScript is language used to write browser-enabled 3D apps and WebGL functions are interface toward GPU.

So, as far as I understand, you want to use Three.js, to convert it to (well, extract) WebGL code, and then convert that to OpenGL.

As I said, Three.js in fact is WebGL, but uses a lot of nifty JavaScript features, so translating JavaScript/WebGL code to Cpp/OpenGL should be straightforward when it comes to drawing API functions, but data structures could be a pain.

About OpenGL to DirectX conversion - well that could be even more complicated, because DX is a object-oriented drawing API, while OpenGL is a state machine. Plus, function names and data structures are very different.

Comment: Okay, so do I clone the three.js repo and try to extract the the WebGL API calls from build->three.js? Moreover, I would need direction in accomplishing this since I don't have much experience with WebGL. All of the other things are after thoughts I just need to extract the WebGL code from the ThreeJS library, are there any utilities that come close to doing this?

Comment: Short answer - yes, extract manually. Tools - no. You go step-by-step though code and through execution phases and "convert" part you need. Use debugging options to go through code, but no tool will do 90% of the work out of the box. All webGL is there, inside Three.js, but you need to find parts that are of interest to you.